# CSS Issues Place Second Article Element Above First

Tags: html, css

I have a section with two news articles the html is correct but the result of the CSS is the second article is above the first. Any suggestions are appreciated thanks in advance.

**Here is an image of the result:**

[image]

**My jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mibb/5sype/2/

**My html:**

```
<section id="loop-news-container">
<h2>NEws</h2>
    <article id="loop-news">
         <a href="#"></a>
         <h1><a href="#">Title of News</a></h1>
         <span>Date of Post 1</span> 
         <img src="image1.jpg" /> 
          <p>Post 1. <a  href="#" >read more</a></p>
    </article>
    <article id="loop-news">
     <a href="#"></a>
         <h1><a href="#">Title 2 Inside of the Post 1</a></h1>
         <span>Date 2 inside of Post 1</span> 
         <img src="image1.jpg" /> 
          <p>Post 2 inside of Post 1<a  href="#" >read more</a></p>
    </article>

</section>
```

**My css:**

```
#loop-news-container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;

}
#loop-news {
    width:320px;
    height:250px;
    background:#fff;
   margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f3f3f3;


}
#loop-news-container h2{font-family:'arial';
    font-size:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-weight:100;
    color:green; 
    text-align:center;}

#loop-news h1 {
    font-family:'arial';
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'arial';
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#loop-news p {font-family:'arial';
    font-size: 17px;  
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:25px;
    height:25px;
    width:310px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }

#loop-news h1 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:100;
    font-family:'arial';
}
#loop-news span {
    font-family:'bariolthin';
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:blue;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;

}

#loop-news a {font-family:'arial';
    font-size:14px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
    margin-left:2px;}

#loop-news img {margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px; width:246px;}
```

Comment: You have two elements with the same Id would suggest using classes instead. I'm not sure if this is causing your issue though just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your tip..but its not the main problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you give a fixed height to `article`.

```
#loop-news {
    /*height:250px;*/
}
```

Recommendation: use class insted of id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is not the problem, or at the least the main problem. Can you see this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/mibb/5sype/4/

Comment: Its like I have a border-bottom in #loop-news and the border-bottom is not at the end of the article. I dont understand why but I guess that´s the problem!

Comment: Why are you using `height` in paragraph `p`?

Comment: Well, good question!! And it was the main problem in this. I dont know why I put that, and I was not to seeing that. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You really already received the correct answer because the height on your element was fixed there was no room for the rest of the html. Since I could not paste code in an comment and I upvoted the given answer I thought I would throw some example code your way. I hope this is what you are looking for and it helps you out. This is what is meant by using classes instead of id's also for core elements you do not need to add parent selector.

```
#loop-news-container {
width:100%;
height:auto;
float:left;
margin-top:5px;
}

.loop-news {
width:320px;
height:auto;
background:#fff;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #f3f3f3;
}

h2 {
font-family:arial;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-weight:100;
color:green;
text-align:center;
}

h1 {
text-align:center;
font-family:arial;
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0 auto;
}

p {
font-family:arial;
font-size:17px;
text-align:justify;
line-height:25px;
width:310px;
margin:0 auto;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:20px;
color:#FF0;
font-weight:100;
font-family:arial;
}

span {
font-family:bariolthin;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:400;
color:blue;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}

img {
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
width:246px;
}


<section id="loop-news-container">
  <h2>NEws</h2>
  <article class="loop-news">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <h1><a href="#">Title of News</a></h1>
  <span>Date of Post 1</span> 
  <img src="image1.jpg" /> 
  <p>Post 1. <a  href="#" >read more</a></p>
  </article>
  <article class="loop-news">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <h1><a href="#">Title 2 Inside of the Post 1</a></h1>
  <span>Date 2 inside of Post 1</span> 
  <img src="image1.jpg" /> 
  <p>Post 2 inside of Post 1<a  href="#" >read more</a></p>
  </article>
</section>
```